# Getting Database Inspector: Error reading Sqlite database. Database not found in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, sqlite

Database Inspector: Error reading Sqlite database: Database 'LiveSqliteDatabaseId(path=/data/data/com.lazeezkhana.app/databases/google_app_measurement_local.db, name=google_app_measurement_local.db, connectionId=1) not found

10:27 PM    Database Inspector: Error reading Sqlite database: Database 'LiveSqliteDatabaseId(path=/data/data/com.lazeezkhana.app/databases/google_app_measurement_local.db, name=google_app_measurement_local.db, connectionId=1) not found

10:27 PM    Database Inspector: Error reading Sqlite database: Database 'LiveSqliteDatabaseId(path=/data/data/com.lazeezkhana.app/databases/google_app_measurement_local.db, name=google_app_measurement_local.db, connectionId=1) not found[image: Image is attached for reference]

Comment: have you got any solution?

Answer (score 1):

It's little bit tricky. Maybe the program not attached properly to emulator during debugging/running app.

But uninstalling app then install again is working for me.